# CSS table-like style

Tags: css

I want to create the following table-like element in my page:
[image]

I used to do it using `<table>...<table>` tags , but now I am switching all my sites to CSS and I'm using DIVs and such. 
I would like to know what is the "best" way to achieve this kind of an element (is it still the `<table>` tag?).
I don't want to create just 3 columns and separate Items in the same column with `<BR />` since I would like to control the spacing between elements in the same column (such as between Item1 and Item4).

Thanks!!

Joel

Comment: CSS is for layouts, tabular content should/can still be displayed in tables

Comment: Use tables for tables silly.

Comment: You can always wait for CSS3!

http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/css3-grid-align/

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid/

Comment: One of the biggest mistakes I see is people who made layouts with tables recreating tables for layout with CSS and then congratulating themselves for making the switch.

Answer (score 11):

use `display:table`, `display:table-row`, `display:table-cell`

```css
#table {display:table;}
.row {display:table-row; }
.cell{display:table-cell;}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Item 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Item 2</div>
    <div class="cell">Item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Item 4</div>
    <div class="cell">Item 5</div>
    <div class="cell">Item 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Item 7</div>
    <div class="cell">Item 8</div>
    <div class="cell">Item 9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Live example http://jsbin.com/awagu4

...but I suggest you to use `table` html tag if you need a table. For this reason exist, and then you can modify it with css. In any case both solutions have the same result.

Comment: if using `div` is your purpose/requirement then go for it. but I would never recommend using divs for creating table like design when `<table>` is already available in `HTML'.

Comment: @Zain Shaikh, I agree, I commented it also after my solution, but this is what he asked.

Comment: That was my first thought, I was just afraid that using DIVs that way might be syntactically wrong :/

Comment: of course yes, when one feature `(<table>)` is available so why not to use that?

Comment: @Joel if you mean if the code is semantically corrrect, a google search about this will solve your question http://www.google.gr/#hl=el&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=921&q=semantic+html&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=bb70ec725b520902

Comment: But unfortunately this won't work in most versions of internet explorer. Given the of your items (grouped in rows rather than columns) it's aachievable using simple css floats

Comment: it needs only a float:left; on .row class to work support and these versions

Comment: just a comment regarding use of CSS. The HTML sample here would be much shorter = less bandwidth for browser, if it made use of CSS hierachy - eg. #table div {/*row*/}  #table div div {/*cell*/} so that you could remove every class="row" and class="cell" from the above HTML

Answer (score 3):

you can achive the same effect with using unordered list nested in a div element

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="itemHolder">
        <li><div>item1</div></li>
        <li><div>item2</div></li>
        <li><div>item3</div></li>
        <li><div>item4</div></li>
        <li><div>item5</div></li>
        <li><div>item6</div></li>
        <li><div>item7</div></li>
        <li><div>item8</div></li>
        <li><div>item9</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this would be your css

```
.wrapper{
    width:600px;
}
.itemHolder{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.itemHolder li{
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.itemHolder li div{
    width:200px;
}
```

you can see it live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D4umD/)

Comment: Easily the most efficient way, though you can just put the "width:200px" on the li and get rid of the divs

Comment: yes, or get rid of the UL/LI and just do it with DIV and "float:left;display:block;"

Comment: @wheresrhys True that, but its safer to work with divs elements, at least for me :) @BerggreenDK its best to keep em organized then just let them float around :)

Answer (score 2):

Flex box is suitable for this.

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap; 
}

li {
     flex-basis: 40%; 
}
```

```html
<ul> 
    <li> item 1</li> 
    <li> item 2</li> 
    <li> item 3 </li> 
    <li> item 4 </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using tables for creating your *layout* is usually frowned upon. Using divs alongside CSS for *tabular* data is also frowned upon. The best way - as asked by your question - is to use tables on this occasion.

Unless of course the items represented in your image is not tabulated data, but containers/boxes which in turn will hold respective data. In which case I would probably recommend CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this with a flexbox.

```
.items {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This will generate a responsive table like structure.

Answer (score 0):

with list style set to none and some use of float you can make a similar result to tables. there's this link: http://mindrulers.blogspot.com/2008/03/create-table-using-css.html and here is it in action: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pJgyu/3247/

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using a design-grid, when doing layouts.

At the moment, I would recommend this "framework": http://960.gs/
The name 960 is because its a design that has 960 pixels width, so that it is viewable on most computers which has minimum 1024 pixels in width. 960 is a great number for dividing into columns etc. but have a look at the website for further info.

Answer (score 0):

In addressing which method you should use:

If this is purely a layout issue and the items have no semantic relation issue I would use  as your container, row and item elements. In which case use something like [Sotiris' answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105338/css-table-like-style/4105391#4105391)

If your items are semantically related then look at who they are related. If they are semantically in groups, i.e. a table use a table, particularly if there would be a title for each column. If it is just generally a group of related items, use a list structure like [cac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105338/css-table-like-style/4105407#4105407) (thoguh it'd probably lose the inner divs).

There are also some interesting variations on the list approach.

By removing the wrapper, or the width from the wrapper in Cac's answer you can create a layout that adjusts it self to different browser width, so for wider screens you'll get less rows of elements as you will get more elements in the row.

Also don't ignore the definition list, if that is a better semantic option to an [unordered list](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/).