# How to format the text below using css

Tags: html, css

My html

```
<p class="ten_mat_hang">Tên mặt hàng:<b>Casio</b></p>
<p class="quoc_gia_ban">Nơi bán:<b>Japan</b></p>
<p class="khoi_luong">Khối lượng:<b>1kg</b></p>
```

returns

Tên mặt hàng:**Casio**

Nơi bán:**Japan**
    Khối lượng:**1kg**

It is not align well. I want "Casio", "Japan", "1kg" to align like below (dash chars are just for aligning purpose)

Tên mặt hàng: Casio

Nơi bán:_____Japan

Khối lượng:__1kg

And I can not use table.
Is is possible to format like above using css?
Thanks

Comment: Can other tags (not table) be introduced within your `p` tag? Without that it would be very difficult.

Comment: yes, other tags can be introduced within my p tag.

Comment: Ok, in that case you don't even have to use `display: table-cell` but if that is fine for you then no issues. Without `table-cell` you could have done something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tdwhrn86/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a table by using:

`display: table` and `table-layout: fixed`

`display: table-cell` and `display: table-row`

Use `ex` as the unit measurement in this case since you have a concern about text spacing. `ex` = the width of 'x' So it's about the width of 1 char at your font.

```css
section {
  width: 30ex;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
div {
  width: 20ex;
  display: table-cell;
}
label {
  display: table-cell;
}
article {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <div>Tên mặt hàng:</div>
    <label>Casio</label>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div>Nơi bán:</div>
    <label>Japan</label>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div>Khối lượng:</div>
    <label>1kg</label>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105391/3619769). Basically you use the `display:table` from CSS.